# How to get a string until a spesific character in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I try to collect to method names from a file. When I take the method name by reading line by line some trash characters come with the method name also.

This is the string:

```
void go(int b) {
```

I want this string like below:

```
void go(int b)
```

So I want to take the string until the ')' char(end of method declaration)

Another example:

```
void stop(); => void stop()
```

Comment: You could try regex `re.search(r"^.+?\)", string)`.

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried but I got this string
`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='void g(int b)'>`

Comment: `re.search(r"(^.+?\))", string).group(1)` - just remember, that if the regex fails e.g. no result is available, it raises an exception.

Comment: no again it didn't work :/

Comment: Couldn't you use something simple like `'void go(int b) {'.split(')')[0] + ')'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the re import to search for special characters in your line of code:

```
import re
string_check= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*;<>?/\|}{~:]')

 
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
 
count = 0
methods = []
for line in Lines:
  methodLine = ""
  for letter in line:
    if not(string_check.search(letter)):
      methodLine += letter
    else:
      break
  methods.append(methodLine)

print(methods)
```

For example, if your text file is:

```
void stop();
void go(int b) {
```

The code would output:

```
['void stop()', 'void go(int b) ']
```

Comment: Your indentation gives me errors when I try it out. :)

Comment: It works for me, maybe just a problem with you copying and pasting it?

Comment: You are correct, my GUI was set to only allow 4 space indent. :)

Comment: I hate when that happens T_T that's why I prefer Java, where the indent can be as crazy as u want lol

Comment: Haha yeah, there's a big difference, but still, your code is correct and it's allowed that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response @AnikethMalyala . I thought there was a quick python method to handle this issue but I guess Python didn't think of it

Comment: @AnikethMalyala Hi again, I have problem with the main function:
The program detects the main function like this : `int main(int argc, const char`
but it should be like this : `int main(int argc, const char[] )`
When I remove the else : break statement then some function's return statements comes with the method name. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what the problem with your code is. The reason the break statement is there is so that it doesn't write in any special characters. When I run the code on my end the text does come out as "int main(int argc, const char[])"

Comment: Are you sure you're copying and pasting the code exactly? Is there a way you can send the part of the text file with that line of code

Answer (score 1):

Since OP could not get my code to work, this is just a proof of concept.

```
import re
string = """void stop(); => void stop()
void go(int b) {
"""
for line in string.splitlines():
    if re.search(r"^.+?\)", line):
        text = re.search(r"(^.+?\))", line).group(1)
        print(text)
```

Result:

```
void stop()
void go(int b)
```

Another example:

```
text = re.findall(r"^.+?\)", string, re.MULTILINE)
print(text)
```

Result:

```
['void stop()', 'void go(int b)']
```